# Generate OAuthBearerTokens within a controller in Webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I have a ASP.NET Webapi2 server that uses OAuthBearerTokens.

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
   TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
   Provider = new MyOAuthProvider(),
   AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
   AllowInsecureHttp = true //in production firewall blocks all insecure connections
};
```

I can log in on /api/token with username and password and get a token in return, this is used in every subsequent requests.

Now I would like to create the functionality of impersonate. Basically a certain (super)user may request to be logged in as another user in the system (without knowing that other users password and passwords are not stored in clear text).

Example: POST: /api/impersonate/[username] that returns same result as /api/token but instead of requiring a password requires the user to have the impersonate priviledge.

Anyone have any guides/tutorials that cover this type of usage? Or could give some hints on where to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your question, you can try to use refresh tokens (that are used as replacement of pair: password and login), it is not easy. I advise you to read this article http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ may be it will be useful for you.